# How to install php_mapscript extension on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I searched over the net for how to install `php_mapscript` extension on WAMP, but found nothing really clear about it.

I tried to install it manually. So I dropped the DLL in the php extensions directory, and added

```
extension=php_mapscript.dll
```

to the `php.ini` file. Now I get the following errors:

> the procedure entry point msMoveLabelStyleUp could not be located in the dynamic link library libmap.dll

and the following in the command line:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.
3.13/ext/php_mapscript.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/
ext/php_mapscript.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.13 (cli) (built: May  8 2012 18:50:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like you may need to load libmap.dll before you load php_mapscript.dll.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use PHP CLI i.e. run php from the command line? It looks like it from your view of the error.

If you are then you have probably changed the wrong php.ini file.

If you use the php.ini link on the wamp menus you will be editing c:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\php.ini this is the php.ini that is used by php when running through Apache ( i.e. on your web site )

There is another php.ini located in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini This is the one used by the php.exe ( i.e PHP CLI )
Edit that file and add the extension=php_mapscript.dll in there, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer I also changed it in every php.ini i had on the machine also I changed it from the wamp menu which is the correct file.
any way I gived up and installed ubuntu as seconed boot, and did

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-mapscript
```

solved all my issues.
and took less time than I spend to find what the .. is going on there.
windows and PHP is not a love story in very soft words.
although wamp did great thing.